# FlowLayout in conjection with setBounds()

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, flowlayout

I have a `JFrame`. I use `setBounds()` for determine position and size, but when I use `frame.setLayout( new FlowLayout() )` all components are cluttered.

What is the solution?

Comment: Swing GUIs might have to work on different platforms, using different PLAFs, on different screen sizes and resolutions with different default settings for font size.  As such, they are not conducive to exact placement of components.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of layout managers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) as well as [layout padding and borders](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17874717/418556) for white space.

Comment: *"`frame.setLayout( new FlowLayout() )` all components are **cluttered.**"*  Needs some white space as alluded to above. Try instead `frame.setLayout( new FlowLayout(align, hgap, vgap) )`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) `setBounds()` is bad practice with null `LayoutManager`(`setLayout(null)`).

2) When you use `FlowLayout`, it calculates positions and sizes of components.

So, you can't mixing 2 approaches. Examine how to use [`LayoutManager`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

Comment: ok,but how can determine size and position of components with FlowLayout?// frame.setLayout( new FlowLayout() );

Comment: [`FlowLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/flow.html) place components one by one in row. Seems you need to use another `BorderLayout` or `GridBagLayout`.